# Can I create a Map with fixed keys?

Tags: typescript, immutability

I need to create a type to represent a set of named switch values. I'd like this type to be immutable in the sense that the switch *names* are fixed, but still allow the switch *value* to be changed.

I am currently using `Map<string, boolean>`. However, that means that a user of my type could add additional key values, or delete the existing key values, and I'd like to prevent that.

I thought about using a `ReadonlyMap<string, boolean>` but while that prevents keys being added or removed, it also prevents setting the switch value :-).

Is there another type that would allow me to have a fixed set of keys, but mutable values?

**EDIT**: something I meant to add to the question is that I don't know the switch names (`Map` keys) at compile time. I'll load the switch names/values and pass them around to various parts of the system; what I'm looking for is a type that I can use in function declarations etc. that expresses the key/value nature of the data, but also the fixed-set-of-keys immutability.

Comment: If You're looking for type which describes this functionality, it's obviously impossible, since You have to know list of keys (switches) at compile time.

Comment: @KrzysztofGrzybek: I don't think that's true. For example, if `ReadonlyMap<K, V>` had a variant that allowed `set(k, v)` *for existing keys* then that would be perfect.

Comment: Yes, but You still have ro provide type `K`, which is not known at compile time, so how would You want to restrict to those keys, if they are not known?

Comment: I should add: this is not possible if you expect error to throw at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what you mean by "I don't know the keys at compile time".  If even the users of your map won't know the keys at compile time, then there's nothing better than `Map<string, boolean>` (although when your keys are strings, a plain-old-JavaScript-object like `{[k: string]: boolean}` is more lightweight and has the same behavior).

If, however, *you* don't know the keys at compile time but the users of your map *do* know them, then you just want to use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) for the key type.

Since you posted no example code I can't target your exact use case, so I'm making stuff up:

```
// your code
class MyMapHolder<K extends string> {
  map: Map<K, boolean>
  constructor(...keys: K[]) {
    this.map = new Map<K, boolean>();
    keys.forEach(k => this.map.set(k, false));
  }      
}

// user's code
const mapHolder = new MyMapHolder("ape", "bee", "cat", "dog", "elk");
mapHolder.map.set("dog", true); // okay
mapHolder.map.set("fox", false); // error, "fox" is not assignable to parameter
```

As you can see, you don't know anything about which keys the user will choose, so you just use `K` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `string`.  But the user of the code specifies some keys, at which point the generic type is instantiated with concrete values... which lets the user know if they try to use an invalid key.

Does that makes sense?  Hope that helps.  Good luck.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks - I wasn't aware of that trick with `K extends string`. I guess I could also remove that extra level of indirection for the caller (`mapHolder.map.set`) if I implement the `set` method directly on the class. Great stuff, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. That's what a class does.

```
class Foo {
    fixedKeyName1: boolean
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I missed something crucial from my question (I'll update it), which is that I don't know the keys at compile time... and I'm not sure that just creating an Object with arbitrary properties really expresses the supposed immutability.